# Django adding related field with multiple databases

Tags: django, many-to-many, multiple-databases

I have a Django project with two databases, each has a game model and a language model that are connected with Many2Many relationships.
When saving each object with: game.save(using=db) I’m able to save to the desired database, but when I attempt to add the related field: game.add(language)
It doesn’t work for the second database.
Any idea why?
*from research I think it might be a problem in my routers.py but I took it from the Django documentation..